# viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad for presenting login popup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController in which it should pop up a LoginViewController if a user is not yet login. The question is where should I call this:

```
LoginViewController* lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    lvc.delegate = self;
    //[lvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:NO];
    [lvc release];
```

should it be in the viewDidLoad or in the viewWillAppear? I guess it makes sense to put it in the viewWillAppear? I tried to put it inside the viewDidLoad and it gives me an extra border to the left and right of the view. Why is this?

**UPDATE:**

What I am trying to do here is to call presentModalViewController on the DetailViewController of a UISplitViewApplication. However nothing happens when I do so. I tried creating a new fresh project of a UISplitViewApplication and still it didn't work.
The question is why? and how do I present a modal view in the viewWillAppear of a UISplitViewApplication

Comment: We need some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal window tries to initialize itself with respect to the view controller that called it (resizing the nib, for example).  Creating and displaying it in its parent's `viewDidLoad` can sometimes give it wrong information since the parent is still itself loading.  This is why you are seeing discrepancies.  Presenting the modal controller in `viewDidAppear` is better in this case since all the parameters are ready to pass to the modal controller so it can load its own view properly.  Though sometimes if you have a lot to load, even that isn't enough and you will need to wait longer before you can present your modal view (which doesn't sound like your case at all, so there should be nothing to worry about there).  I hope this helps, though

Comment: why is it that I can't do a presentModalViewController int he DetailViewController of a UISplitViewApplication?

Comment: I've added some comment above

Comment: I was able to present a modal view from my detail view controller just fine, so I'm not entirely sure what is going on with your code.  One thing I notice is in your modal view controller declaration.  Unless you are loading it within the `init` method, you will need to specify `LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourLoginVCNibName" bundle:nil];`  Otherwise it has no nib to load from and will give you a blank screen.  This might fix your problem.  If not, we'll figure it out

Comment: slev.. I just started a fresh project with an UISplitView, add a new UIViewController (loginviewcontroller) with some buttons, etc in it, and just did the code above... nothing there.. can you send me your fresh project possibly to aditya15417@gmail.com?

Comment: I recorded a short 2 minute video to show you what I've done http://www.screenr.com/pjI. Let me know what I did wrong

Comment: Alright, I just set up a fresh split view project and got a modal window presented on viewDidAppear, so I'll put it in a zip file and send it to you now

Comment: The only thing I see in your video that you need to put in is the `initWithNibName` in your modal view controller creation.  I'm still going to send you this fresh project so you can mess around with it that way, but I think that is all you would need to change.  (also, xcode 4 looks nice, I'm a bit jealous)

Comment: I did that and it didn't work still...looking forward to your project

Comment: I sent it a while ago to the email you gave, so it should be there by now

Answer (score 0):

I would place something like this in the AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    [self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    

    // Show the login screen if the user hasn't logged in yet
if (... login check here...)
  {
    LoginViewController* loginController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [self.viewController presentModalViewController:loginController animated:NO];
    [loginController release];
  }
}
```

Your login screen will be placed on top of your normal viewcontroller. After a succesfull login dismiss the LoginViewController and your user can start using your app.

Comment: there is no self.viewController in my appdelegate

Comment: Offcourse you should replace that part with your own viewcontroller ;)

Comment: if you are familiar with UISplitView, can you take a look at my 2 minute video at the comment on slev's post?

Comment: You can't do self.viewController. You need to let your view load first then present the modal on top of it... Do this in the viewDidAppear or at some point after viewDidAppear.

Comment: I tried this with `self.window?.rootViewController`. However the view is not in the windows hierarchy at this point as it hasn't been loaded.

Comment: While if I add`makeKeyAndVisible` I get the following error `NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.`, I think for a modal viewController viewDidAppear is likely the correct approach.